# PHP image re-sizing

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that re-sizes my JPEG images. But, for some reason The images are being distorted, even though I programmed it to calculate the x or y (depending on the photo orientation) proportionally. The quality is 100, so I don't get why it would be making them distorted. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The original image is 3264px x 2448px

The original Image:
http://imgur.com/DOsKf&hMAOh#0

Re-sized: 
http://imgur.com/DOsKf&hMAOh#1

Thanks

The Code:

```
<?php

$im = ImageCreateFromJpeg('IMG_0168.jpg');

//Find the original height and width.

$ox = imagesx($im);
$oy = imagesy($im);

//Now we will determine the new height and width. For this example maximum height will    
be 500px and the width will be 960px. To prevent inproper proportions we need to know 
if the image is portrate or landscape then set one dimension and caluate the other. 

$height = 500;
$width = 960;
if($ox < $oy)   #portrate
{
   $ny = $height;
   $nx = floor($ox * ($ny / $oy)); 
} 
else #landscape
{
   $nx = $width;
   $ny = floor($oy * ($nx / $ox)); 
} 

//Then next two functions will create a new image resource then copy the original image     
to the new one and resize it.

$nm = imagecreatetruecolor($nx, $ny);
imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $ox, $oy);

//Now we just need to save the new file.

imagejpeg($nm, 'smallerimagefile2.jpg', 100);

?>
```

Comment: the only likely distortion I can image is when the original image is smaller than the output image. what are the dimensions of "IMG_0168.jpg"?

Comment: Can you show an example of the original image and the resized one ?

Comment: I added the original dimensions, and the photos to my post! Thanks guys

Comment: It's not distorted, it's because of all the lines and the resizing, maybe the answer from @gurudeb will do a better job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Use***

> imagecopyresampled($nm, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $ox, $oy);

***Instead of***

> imagecopyresized($nm, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nx, $ny, $ox, $oy);

### Explanation:

imagecopyresized() allows you to change the size of an image quickly and easily, but has the downside of producing fairly low-quality pictures. imagecopyresampled() which takes the same parameters as imagecopyresized() and works in the same way with the exception that the resized image is smoothed. The downside is that the smoothing takes more CPU effort, so the image takes longer to produce.

**Details of the functions:**

- imagecopyresampled: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php
- imagecopyresized: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0):

It's all down to the algorithms that are used during the scaling process. If you use an image editor like Gimp, you'll see the different interpolation algorithms that it can use (i.e. Linear, Cubic, etc). The more complex the algorithm the better the scaled image result, but the more processing it takes and so longer time is required.

I don't know if you can change the algorithm that GD uses, but I believe you can if you use the ImageMagick library in PHP.